# Pooling PBOs and textures?

Tags: c++, opengl

I have an application which does a lot of GPGPU using Opengl and Pixel Buffer Objects to transfer and process data.

Currently I employ a pooling of these resources, basically I have a pool for every buffer dimensions and usage that my application uses. When the usage of resource finishes it returns to its respective pool for re-use. However, I'm starting to have seconds thoughts whether there is any is in this since I need "orphan" the PBOs before re-use to not interfere with ongoing transfers.

My question is whether there is any merit is in pooling resources such as PBOs and textures, or would it be just a good to simply allocate from OpenGL directly when needed?

Here is an example of what I am doing. Vice versa with textures.

```
std::shared_ptr<pbo> create_pbo(int size, bool write)
{
    auto pool = pbo_pools[write][size];
    std::shared_ptr<pbo> buffer;
    if(!pool->try_pop(buffer))  
        buffer = ogl_thread_.invoke([=]{return new pbo(size, write);}); 

    return spl::shared_ptr<pbo>(buffer.get(), [=](pbo*) mutable
    {
        ogl_thread_.begin_invoke([=]() mutable
        {       
            if(write)
                buffer->map();
            else // read
                buffer->unmap();

            pool->push(buffer);
        }); 
    });
}
```

Comment: @ronag: Off-topic, but what am I looking at here?  That's like no C++ that I've seen.  C++11?

Comment: @genpfault: Yes, C++11. The invoke, begin_invoke methods is just from a class that wraps function execution on a thread instance.

Comment: @ronag For *pooling* do you mean managing them in a memory pool?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm starting to have seconds thoughts whether there is any is in this since I need "orphan" the PBOs before re-use to not interfere with ongoing transfers.

No you don't have to. That's the nice thing about PBOs: You can submit new data into them, while a call to glTex(Sub)Image may still be reading from them, without the read operation being corrupted.

Comment: According to this, http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object_Streaming, you should orphan PBOs before writing new data to them.

Comment: @ronag: Calling glBufferDate(..., data), is defined as being equivalent to glBufferData(..., 0), glBufferSubDate(..., data). The idea of orphaning is to prepare a fresh buffer, if you want to map the buffer using glMapBuffer without forcing OpenGL into synchronization. But if you just want to upload new data it's not necessary.

Comment: "glMapBuffer without forcing OpenGL into synchronization", is what I want to do... without writing something to the PBO there is no new data to upload?

Comment: Just realized your question depends on which direction you mean by upload/download, either way I am doing both.

Comment: @ronag: The usual approach is to use multiple buffer objects, i.e. doing data transfer on one, while the other is being utilized internally by OpenGL.

Comment: I am doing that. How does this relate to my question?

Comment: @datenwolf You must use glBufferData like prescribed in the OpenGL Wiki (eg: with null pointer) to orphan the pixel buffers, and not glBufferSubData

Comment: @Gigi: Yes of course. Read my comment again. glBufferSubData is preceded by a orpahning glBufferData call.

Comment: @datenwolf *Calling glBufferData(..., data), is defined as being equivalent to glBufferData(..., 0), glBufferSubData(..., data)* - My friend, it is equivalent only if you don't care about speed.

Comment: @Gigi: Did you measure it? The difference is only in the overhead of the function calls. glBufferData will reinitialize/orphan the bufer object, but not upload anything. glBufferSubData will just upload the data, but keep the buffer object layout. This is the same rationale behind glTexStorage – separate buffer initialization and population.

Comment: @datenwolf You *discard* the old buffer data so the driver can assume that all operations that require the old data have been issued.

Comment: @datenwolf glTexStorage let you fine-tune the storage of your texture objects, so that you can have for example a mipmap pyramid where each level is something other than the half of the previous.

Comment: @Gigi: You could have that before as well. You just had to be ultra carefull to setup the texture levels correctly as to not mess up the whole texture object by a wrong parametized call to glTexImage. glTexStorage basically freezes the texture object's buffer layout, so that you can not mess it up. Technically we could introduce the same for buffer objects as well. Also I ask you again: Did you actually measure the difference of `glBufferData(..., 0); glBufferSubData(..., data);` vs `glBufferData(..., data);`? I'm using the former in many of my programs, because the difference is neglectible.

Comment: @datenwolf I've not measured the difference, but you seem to have done it. You tell that the difference is negligible, but in what direction? Slower? However the difference can actually be 0 given the fact that *discarding* is not a thing mandated by standards, but merely an hint to the driver.

Comment: @Gigi: It adds a *constant* overhead, which mainly stems from function call overhead. Also OpenGL is free about when it actually deallocates the buffer objects that had the used ID before (this is the main idea of orphaning: reassinging an existing ID to a new buffer object, while references to the old one may still be held internally). In the driver code itself, if data is passed to glBufferData, the driver will go through the very same codepath as glBufferSubData after initialization. OpenGL is a very abstract thing.

Comment: @datenwolf In the driver code: when you call glBufferData on a buffer that you have previously *discarded* (by calling *glBufferData(.., 0)*) then you are just allocating a new buffer. So why the need to discard? To let the driver know that we don't care anymore for the old data, so it can *eventually* do something clever. If you instead use glBufferSubData then the same very thing can happen, but also can't. So yes Opengl is a very abstract thing, but drivers are not.

Comment: I think you clearly misunderstood what `glBufferData(..., 0)` means. It just tells OpenGL "initialize a new buffer object of requested size on the currently bound ID". Passing a null pointer is not some special side channel API to discard buffer objects. It just creates a new buffer object, but the buffer object previously associated with the used ID may still be referenced internally, you just can't re-bind it anymore.

Comment: This is like deleting a file on a POSIX OS: As long as some process holds a opened file descriptor on it, the storage allocated by the file gets not freed, even if you remove the filesystem entry.

Comment: Then why the OpenGL wiki explicitly talk about *glBufferData(..., 0)* and *glMapBufferRange(.., GL_MAP_INVALIDATE_BUFFER_BIT)* but not about *glBufferSubData(..., 0)* ??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7576/discussion-between-datenwolf-and-gigi)

Comment: @datenwolf: _Now_ I understand your answer. Sorry for the confusion.